# Como paralelizar em vários níveis no R?

Tags: r, loop, paralelismo

Estive pesquisando como paralelizar o `for` no R e encontrei o package `foreach`, que, pelo que eu entendi e corrijam me se estiver errado, substitui o `for` da seguinte forma:

```
library(foreach)
vetor <- rep(NA, 10)
n <- seq_len(10)
foreach(j = n) %dopar% {
vetor[j] <- j + 1
}
```

Minha questão como fazer em um caso onde tenho `for(){for(){}}`, `for(){for(){for(){}}}`... É possível subparalelizar?

Comment: Parece que a resposta está no operador `%:%`. [Veja](https://www.r-bloggers.com/the-wonders-of-foreach/).

Comment: Acabei de descobrir terei que estudar o ´library(doParallel)´ para fazer o ´library(foreach)´ funcionar melhor.

Comment: @TomásBarcellos a importância do operador é que com `%do%` esta função é igual ao `for` e com %dopar% é a versão paralelizada. Contudo antes tem que se configurar a paralelização com o `doParallel`.

Comment: Usar `%dopar%` sem configurar antes com `doParallel` não adianta. Antes de roda o código com `foreach(...) %dopar%{...}`, você precisará rodar `doParallel::registerDoParallel()`. Depois é só fechar o cluster criado com `doParallel::stopImplicitCluster()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em geral não compensa paralelizar em mais de um nível. Isso até que é possível mas não vai fazer o seu código rodar mais rápido, a não ser que o primeiro nível de paralelismo não esteja conseguindo utilizar todo o recurso ocioso do computador.

Hoje em dia a forma mais fácil de se criar código paralelo no R é usando o pacote [`future`](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future) em combinação com o [`furrr`](https://github.com/DavisVaughan/furrr).

Veja aqui um exemplo clássico de paralelização:

```r
library(furrr)
#> Loading required package: future
library(purrr)
plan(multisession)

fun <- function(x) {
  Sys.sleep(1)
  x
}

system.time(
  map(1:4, fun)  
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.004   0.001   4.020

system.time(
  future_map(1:4, fun)  
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.077   0.012   1.297
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

No exemplo, a versão paralela demora um pouco mais de 1s enquanto a versão sequencial demora 4s, como esperado.

Agora vamos adicionar um segundo nível de paralelização.

```r
library(furrr)
#> Loading required package: future
library(purrr)
plan(multisession)

fun <- function(x) {
  Sys.sleep(1)
  x
}

system.time(
  future_map(1:4, ~map(1:4, fun))  
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.090   0.012   4.391

system.time(
  future_map(1:4, ~future_map(1:4, fun))  
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.065   0.005   4.223
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Veja que as duas formas levam tempos muito similares. Isso acontece a pois primeira paralelização já usa todo o recurso ocioso de CPU do computador, o segundo nível da paralelização não consegue ganhar mais espaço.

O primeiro nível poderia não estar utilizando todos os recursos do computador, se por exemplo, meu computador tivesse 8 cores ao invés de 4, paralelizar apenas no primeiro nível deixaria 4 cores sub-utilizados. Neste caso faria sentido fazer a paralelização no segundo nível. No entanto, isso é raro. Em geral paralelizamos loops em que o número de iterações é > do que o número de cores.